# Signed GRUB booting UEFI PXE Windows 10 PE, finally unable to find sbcpflighttoken.p7b and friends

Tags: windows, boot, grub, uefi, pxe

I'm trying to boot Windows 10 amd64 preboot environment (PE) iso I created with Windows ADK + the "PE addon". I'm trying to use signed boot shim and signed GRUB for this.

First I use Debian 10.5.0 amd64 stuff (grub-common, grub-efi-amd64-bin, grub-efi-amd64-signed, shim-signed.):

In my /tftproot I have symlinked:

```
bootx64.efi -> /opt/efipkgs/debian/shim-signed/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi.signed
grubx64.efi -> /opt/efipkgs/debian/grub-efi-amd64-signed/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubnetx64.efi.signed
grub/x86_64-efi -> /opt/efipkgs/debian/grub-efi-amd64-bin/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi
grub/fonts/ascii.pf2 -> /opt/efipkgs/debian/grub-common/usr/share/grub/ascii.pf2
grub/fonts/euro.pf2 -> /opt/efipkgs/debian/grub-common/usr/share/grub/euro.pf2
grub/fonts/unicode.pf2 -> /opt/efipkgs/debian/grub-common/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2
```

I have Secure boot enabled in my motherboard UEFI Setup. Now, when I boot I get this GRUB menu just fine:

[Grub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaT7Q.jpg)

I have a menu for booting the local disk Windows 7/10 on GPT:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7/10 EFI bootloader on local GPT' {
 insmod part_gpt
 insmod fat
 insmod chain
 set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
 chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Boots Windows 10 (was installed in non-secureboot mode) from local disk just fine:

[Disk windows booted fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4SKl.jpg)

So the chainloading efi is somewhat working.

However, if I try to boot this menu entry:

```
menuentry 'GRUP WINPE TEST' {
 chainloader /unpacked_isos/win10/winpe_win10_x64_2021-10-09/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
}
```

like here:

[Grub Winpe Debian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuJPg.jpg)

I get the following error "BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc0000001":

[BlInitializeLibrary failed 0xc0000001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS13H.jpg)

OK. So next for fun I try Ubuntu trusty packages. I take them for example from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/shim-signed/1.6+0.4-0ubuntu4 and here: [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/grub-efi-amd64-signed/1.34+2.02~beta2-9](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/grub-efi-amd64-signed/1.34+2.02%7Ebeta2-9) .

I make new symlinks:

```
bootx64.efi -> /opt/efipkgs/ubuntu/shim-signed/usr/lib/shim/shim.efi.signed
grubx64.efi -> /opt/efipkgs/ubuntu/grub-efi-amd64-signed/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubnetx64.efi.signed
grub/x86_64-efi -> /opt/efipkgs/ubuntu/grub-efi-amd64-bin/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi
grub/fonts/ascii.pf2 -> /opt/efipkgs/ubuntu/grub-common/usr/share/grub/ascii.pf2
grub/fonts/euro.pf2 -> /opt/efipkgs/ubuntu/grub-common/usr/share/grub/euro.pf2
grub/fonts/unicode.pf2 -> /opt/efipkgs/ubuntu/grub-common/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2
```

And look, a miracle happens, I get a bit forward :

[Windows Boot Manager Server IP unable to find \Boot\BCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGpLB.jpg)

So the screen says "Windows Boot Manager (Server IP: 172.16.8.254). And it tells it is unable to find \Boot\BCD

Well this is still fixable. Lets link boot directory to main level

```
ln -s unpacked_isos/win10/winpe_win10_x64_2021-10-09/boot boot
```

Looking at the logs

```
Oct 10 17:22:20 gw dnsmasq-tftp[27274]: sent /tftproot/unpacked_isos/win10/winpe_win10_x64_2021-10-09/efi/boot/bootx64.efi to 172.16.8.197
Oct 10 17:22:20 gw dnsmasq-tftp[27274]: file /tftproot/Boot/BCD not found
```

Some kind of case problem. Lets just force everything lowercase on dnsmasq tftp server with following directive:

```
tftp-lowercase
```

After restarting dnsmasq a new try:

[Windows boot manager server ip 0xc0000225 unexpected error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNTNP.jpg)

So a different error code, this time 0xc0000225 / unexpected error.

Look at tftp logs:

```
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: sent /tftproot/unpacked_isos/win10/winpe_win10_x64_2021-10-09/efi/boot/bootx64.efi to 172.16.8.197
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: error 0 TFTP Aborted received from 172.16.8.197
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: failed sending /tftproot/boot/bcd to 172.16.8.197
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: sent /tftproot/boot/bcd to 172.16.8.197
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/policies/sbcpflighttoken.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/securebootpolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/sipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/skusipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/winsipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/atpsipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/sipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/skusipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/winsipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/atpsipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/sipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/skusipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/winsipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/atpsipolicy.p7b not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/fonts/wgl4_boot.ttf not found
Oct 10 17:30:42 gw dnsmasq-tftp[28488]: file /tftproot/efi/microsoft/boot/fonts/wgl4_boot.ttf not found
```

If I disable secure boot in motherboard Uefi Setup, situation is completely the same.

So my questions:

1. Why old(?) Ubuntu 14.04 grub stuff is able to get this far in secure booting and Debian not?
2. Where are the missing p7b files located? Or should they be at all available as I have created
   my .iso in a custom way with Windows ADK?

Sidenote: I *can* and probably will find a way to boot at least unsecure images in Uefi PXE (via self-compiled ipxe or GRUB4DOS for UEFI for exampe, but I was just wondering what is going on here (:D) and if this can be done with Grub, etc. Cheers.